# Difficulty merging SignalR code into if statement

Tags: jquery, signalr

I tried to merge the following code

```
   // main chat code

    $(function () {

        var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

        IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
            $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        };

        $("#sendMessage").click(function () {
            IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
        });

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

into the **below** function, but it doesn't seem to work any more (note that the below function shows the current project status).

```
$(function () {

    $("#sendMessage").click(function () {
        $('#ideaTitle,#ideaBody').each(function () {

            var $this = $(this),
                currValue = this.value,
                trimmedValue = $.trim(currValue),
                dataValue = $this.data('default');

            if (trimmedValue.length === 0 && (trimmedValue === dataValue)) {
                var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub
                IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
                    $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
                };
                IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
                $.connection.hub.start();
            } else if (trimmedValue.length === 0) {
                alert('empty');
                return false;
            } else if (trimmedValue === dataValue) {
                alert('default');
                return false;
            }
        })
    });

});
```

I am trying to validate 2 fields before submission - if the 2 fields meet the validation requirements then I want to send the message. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: @SLaks the message is not sent if all validation requirements are met... I get alerts if there is something wrong but nothing happens if everything is working ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code which starts and sends a message to the hub is wrong.

```
if (trimmedValue.length === 0 && (trimmedValue === dataValue)) {
    var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub
    IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
    };
    IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
    $.connection.hub.start();
}
```

Notice that you are attempting to post to the hub before you have even started the connection.

I would suggest changing your code to;

```
if (trimmedValue.length === 0 && (trimmedValue === dataValue)) {
    var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub
    IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
    };    
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
    });
}
```

This way the connection has been started, and only once it is complete it will attempt to call the `send` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
trimmedValue.length === 0 && (trimmedValue === dataValue)
```

You probably want to check whether both of those are *false*, not true.

Or just move that to a final `else`.

---

Also, all of that code will execute twice; once for each round of the `each()`.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it?